# How do I resolve missing aur libraries in arch linux?

Tags: arch-linux

```
 -> Missing AUR Packages:  kalarmcal
 -> Missing AUR Debug Packages:  libkipi-debug
```

How do I resolve this in Arch?

Comment: Most likely these are packages that used to be in the AUR but got removed because the maintainer lost interest. Do you already have these packages installed, or do you need to install them as dependencies for something else? For kalarmcal there's [kalarmcal-git](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/kalarmcal-git) you could replace it with. For the other, you can remove it if you don't need it. You could just use your current version if it still works. Or you could adopt it and maintain it yourself!